# Newest additions to java.nio not found; using java 1.7.0_9

Tags: java, package, java-7, java.nio.file

So I'm using Java SE 1.7.0_9 (which I think is the latest version) and I'm trying to do things with files using the java.nio.file.Files class. However, anytime I attempt to access one of the classes added to the java.nio package in Java release 7 (such as .file or .attribute), the  compiler returns this error:

```
attend.java:4: package java.nio.file does not exist
import java.nio.file.*;
^
attend.java:5: package java.nio.file.attribute does not exist
import java.nio.file.attribute.*;
^
2 errors
```

I thought perhaps I was wrong about the version I was using, so I checked my version and it returned this:

```
[04:31 PM]java: java -version
java version "1.7.0_09"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_09-b05)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.5-b02, mixed mode)
```

I honestly can't figure out what's going on. Can anyone help me on this?

**EDIT:** I would also like to point out that the new try-with-resources statement, which was introduced in Java SE 7, also makes my compiler complain that it's not a valid statement. It's as if I'm not actually using Java SE 7 at all, and it's very frustrating.

**SOLVED:** As it turns out, though these machines are running Java SE 1.7.0_9, they default to the 1.6.0_37 version of the javac compiler. All I needed to do was mess with the path to make sure it went to the 1.7.0 version instead. Thanks for the help!

Comment: are you on Linux? I have the same problem

Answer (score 1):

Clearly you aren't compiling with JDK 1.7 at all, but with an earlier JDK. Check your settings.

Comment: I don't know to mess with my settings, or if I even have permission to. I'm using a network down at IUB, and running java on their server. If I did have permission, though, how would I go about changing the settings? This is a RedHat machine

Answer (score 0):

Another, more far fetched error, would be that you let your JDK 1.7 compile for 1.6. This is a compiler command line option, IDE option, maven option.

Answer (score -1):

Check if you are referencing the correct JDK. If you are using Eclipse you should specify it in 'Properies'-'Java build path'-'Libraries'

Comment: A question is not an answer, and he needs a JDK for compiling, not a JRE.

Comment: I'm not using any particular IDE, just emacs on a RedHat machine.